# IOS: reverse geocodign province

Tags: ios, xcode, reverse-geocoding

I have this code to reverse geocoding and it work

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    MKPlacemark * myPlacemark = placemark;
    // with the placemark you can now retrieve the city name
    NSString *region = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressStateKey];
    NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressCityKey];
    NSString *address = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
    NSLog(@"region:%@", region);
    NSLog(@"city:%@", city);
    NSLog(@"address:%@", address);

}
```

It work fine but I'm not able to have "province"...what's the way to obtain province?

Answer (score 0):

These are all the keys for the address dictionary:

```
const ABPropertyID kABPersonAddressProperty;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStreetKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCityKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStateKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressZIPKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCountryKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey;
```

> **Constants**
>   **kABPersonAddressProperty**
>  Identifier for the address multivalue property.
>  Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>   Declared in ABPerson.h.
>   **kABPersonAddressStreetKey**
>  Street.
>  Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>  Declared in ABPerson.h.
>   **kABPersonAddressCityKey** City.
>  Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>  Declared in ABPerson.h.
>   **kABPersonAddressStateKey**
>  State.
>  Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>  Declared in ABPerson.h.
>   **kABPersonAddressZIPKey**
>  Zip code.
>  Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>  Declared in ABPerson.h.
>   **kABPersonAddressCountryKey**
>  Country.
>  Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>  Declared in ABPerson.h.
>   **kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey**
>  Country code. The supported values are listed in “Country Codes.”
>  Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later.
>  Declared in ABPerson.h.

Unfortunately there isn't one for province.

Comment: and there isn't a way to obtain province?

Comment: Probably there isn't. I think province is a country-specific territory for some countries only and therefore it's not included, but could be possible to take it out from the State, but I am not sure if it fills there, give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

In My code, I have following ways to get address and place names.
Province is State or administrativeArea

```
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if(placemarks.count){

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] addressDictionary];
        addressLabel.Text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Street"];
        cityLabel.Text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"City"];
        stateLabel.Text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"State"];
        zipCodeLabel.Text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"ZIP"];
        countryLabel.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Country"];
        countryCodeLabel.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"CountryCode"];


        placeNameLabel.text = [placemarks[0] name];
        addressNumberLabel.text = [placemarks[0] subThoroughfare];
        addressLabel.text = [placemarks[0] thoroughfare];
        neighborhoodLabel.text = [placemarks[0] subLocality];
        cityLabel.text = [placemarks[0] locality];
        countyLabel.text = [placemarks[0] subAdministrativeArea];
        stateLabel.text = [placemarks[0] administrativeArea];
        zipCodeLabel.text = [placemarks[0] postalCode];
        countryLabel.text = [placemarks[0] country];
        countryCodeLabel.text = [placemarks[0] ISOcountryCode];
        inlandWaterLabel.text = [placemarks[0] inlandWater];
        oceanLabel.text = [placemarks[0] ocean];
    }
}];
```

You can try my open source project. It is easy to get place marks. [Device-Details](https://github.com/robert-yi-jones/Device-Details) https://github.com/robert-yi-jones/Device-Details